# Wie kann man Partizip 1 intepretieren?

Tags: grammaticality

In dem folgenden Beispiel:

> kochendes Fleisch

ist Fleisch, das kocht. Das heißt, das Fleisch ist im Topf bzw. im Wasser und kocht.

Was bedeutet aber der folgende Satz?

> eine kochende Frau

Ist das eine Frau in einem Topf, die zum Beispiel für das Essen eines Kannibalenstammes gekocht wird oder heißt es eine Frau, die am Herd steht und das Essen vorbereitet.

Ich denke, beides könnte richtig sein und man kann nur aus dem Kontext die Bedeutung herausfinden.

Comment: Sie könnte auch vor Wut kochen

Comment: Deine Vermutung ist richtig, die Bedeutung lässt sich nur über den Kontext herausfinden.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Antwort im Kommentar? Sollte nicht sein... ;-)

Comment: @infinitezero: Wenn die Dame 'vor Wut kocht', wird man selbst im Fall eines Partizipialattributs nicht umhin kommen, das auch ausdrücklich hinzuschreiben: *'_Kochend stürmte sie aus dem Laden und brach sich im Fußabtreter den Stöckel ihres rechten Schuhs ab._' oder '*_Die kochende Frau wirkte äußerlich ganz ruhig._'

Comment: Zur Frage selbst würde ich sagen, dass mir das Beispiel mit der Frau im Kochtopf mir ein wenig konstruiert erscheint und daher für mich kein Bedarf an der Klärung dieser Frage besteht.

Comment: @Stephie dieser eine Satz wäre viel zu dünn gewesen, um ihn als Antwort so stehen zu lassen - hätte ich das getan, wären vermutlich von mehreren Leuten Hinweise gekommen, dass das eher ein Kommentar ist ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Frage ist unabhängig vom Partizip 1, da die finiten Formen schon dieselbe Mehrdeutigkeit aufweisen: Ist das Subjekt Agens oder Patiens?

> Sie kocht die Suppe.
>   Die Suppe kocht.

In der englischsprachigen Linguistik spricht man in Fällen wie den folgenden von [causative alternation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative_alternation#Anticausatives). Das transitive Verb ist kausativ, das intransitive "antikausativ" (etwas geschieht "von alleine").

> Sie trockneten ihre Kleider.
>   Ihre Kleider trockneten.
>
> Er rollte das Fahrrad in die Garage.
>   Das Fahrrad rollte noch ein paar Meter weiter.
>
> Er zerbrach den Besen.
>   Der Besen zerbrach.

Bei *kochen* haben sich die Bedeutungen ausdifferenziert: Wenn jemand eine Suppe kocht, geht es um die Zubereitung einer Speise und nicht um das Erhitzen bis zum Siedepunkt; wenn die Suppe kocht, ist es genau umgekehrt.

Die Ambiguität im Partizip 1 ensteht dadurch, daß das Objekt des transitiven Verbs *kochen* optional ist.

> eine kochende Frau
>   1. eine etwas kochende Frau (transitiv)
>   2. eine im Pott der Kannibalen kochende Frau (intransitiv)

Als Ersatz für 2. kommen *köcheln* und *vor sich hinköcheln* infrage, die keine Mehrdeutigkeit aufweisen und bei denen das Subjekt das Patiens ist (also das, was gekocht wird).

> eine im Pott köchelnde Frau
>   eine im Pott vor sich hinköchelnde Frau

Comment: @Olafant Mit dem *vor sich hin köcheln* bist du dir sicher? https://german.stackexchange.com/q/56368/35111

Comment: @DavidVogt Jepp. Das *hin* gehört zu *vor sich hin* und nicht zu *köcheln*.

Comment: @DavidVogt Habe das mal als Antwort zu der anderen Frage formuliert. Wundert mich ein bisschen, dass du die zusammengeschriebene Variante gewählt hast. Gibt es dafür einen Grund? Wenn ja, fände ich es ganz interessant, wenn du den in die Frage mit aufnimmst.

Comment: Wie ist es mit Partizip 2 von *kochen* als Attribut - *eine gekhochte Frau*? Ich vermute, hier heißt es nur *eine Frau, die im Pott der Kannibalen gekochte wurde*. Oder gibt es hier auch Ambiguität?

Comment: Und dann wäre natürlich die im Pott (=Ruhrgebiet) vor sich hin köchelnde Frau...

Comment: @Infinity Bei transitiven Verben bezieht sich das Partizip II immer auf das Objekt/Patiens.

Comment: @Olafant Sogar, wenn wir nur den Duden gelten lassen würden, wäre Zusammenschreibung auch möglich: *vor sich hin brummen, murmeln usw., seltener auch hinbrummen, hinmurmeln usw.* https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hin

Comment: @DavidVogt Na das widerspricht nicht meiner [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56378/36196).