# Schreibung von "vor sich hin" plus Verb

Tags: spelling

Das Deutsche kennt Verbindungen von *vor sich hin* mit Verben. Die Bedeutung wurde in [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7802/meaning-of-vor-sich-hin) thematisiert. Mich interessiert die Schreibung.

Der Duden hat unter [vor](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vor_bevor_aus_gegen_heraus) 1b:

> vor sich hin (ganz für sich und in gleichmäßiger Fortdauer: vor sich hin schimpfen, reden, weinen)

Aber man findet auch:

> Lieder, die sie halblaut vor sich hinsang. (Musil, [Törleß](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/musil/toerless/chap002.html))
>
> denken Sie an die Studienreformkommissionen, die
>   immer noch vor sich hinschlafen (Bayerischer Landtag, [Plenarprotokoll](http://www.bayern.landtag.de/www/ElanTextAblage_WP11/Protokolle/11%20Wahlperiode%20Kopie/11%20WP%20Plenum%20LT%20Kopie/016%20PL%20180387%20ges%20endg%20Kopie.pdf))
>
> QUINKELIEREN [...] *vor sich hinsingen* ([DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=quinkelieren))

Gibt es Gründe, die eine Schreibweise der anderen vorzuziehen?

Comment: vor sich hinsingen - That's not how the Duden would write it (->misspelling): https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/leise%20vor%20sich%20hin%20singen Maybe the spelling changed in the last reform and some people do not accept it.

Comment: @mic Aber siehe https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hin

Answer (score 3):

> Er fütterte die Hühner, indem er die Körner träumend vor sich hin warf.

Er wirft die Körner irgendwo hin, ohne weiter darauf zu achten.

> Er fütterte die Hühner, indem er die Körner träumend vor sich hinwarf.

Er wirft die Körner vor sich auf den Boden.

Bei Musils Satz

> Lieder, die sie halblaut vor sich hinsang.

könnte man sagen, dass sie ja tatsächlich in eine Richtung singt, dass sie also (halblaut) in die unmittelbare Umgebung vor sich hinsingt (und nicht etwa zu einem großen Publikum hin). Das ist aber ziemlich subtil und funktioniert auch nur bei einigen Verben. Bei anderen Verben wie

- schlafen -> hinschlafen?
- köcheln -> hinköcheln?

macht das keinen Sinn. Bei wieder anderen ist es offensichtlich falsch:

> Als er so vor sich hin ging.

meint ja nicht, dass er einen Schritt vorwärts machte, also *vor sich hinging*. In diesen Fällen gehört das *hin* eindeutig zu der Wendung *vor sich hin* und nicht zum Verb.

Comment: Die Unterscheidung zwischen Ort ([vor sich hin] [gehen]) und Richtung ([vor sich] [hingehen]) ist meines Erachtens der Kern des Problems. Und da die Antwort diesen Kern aufgreift, werte ich sie auf.

Answer (score 1):

Goethe, Gefunden, beginnt so:

> Ich ging im Walde / So vor mich hin, / und nichts zu suchen, / Das war mein Sinn.

würde nach diesem Muster zu:

> Als Goethe im Walde vor sich hinging, ...

*Hingehen* hat aber eine ganz andere Bedeutung, deshalb würde ich die getrennte Schreibung bevorzugen, zudem sich *hin* stark auf *sich* und nicht auf das Verb bezieht.

Mir ist auch schleierhaft, was *hinschlafen* bedeuten könnte, regelgerechte Bildung des Wortes hin oder her.

Answer (score 0):

Wie in der Frage erwähnt, findet man beide Schreibungen; dabei scheint Getrenntschreibung häufiger als Zusammenschreibung. Während die Frage nur *vor* zitiert, findet man im Duden unter *hin* auch die andere Schreibung erwähnt.

> vor sich hin brummen, murmeln usw., seltener auch hinbrummen, hinmurmeln usw. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hin)

Da sich schon zwei Antworten für die Getrenntschreibung ausgesprochen haben, soll in dieser Antwort nach möglichen Gründen für Zusammenschreibung gesucht werden.

1. Die Zusammenschreibung wirkt aufgrund der eingesparten Spatien ästhetischer. Am deutlichsten ist der Effekt beim zu-Infinitiv.

   > vor sich hinzumurmeln
   >   vor sich hin zu murmeln
2. Es gibt das Argument, daß *hin* zu *vor sich* und nicht zum Verb gehöre, was man daran erkennen könne, daß die Verben *hin*+V nicht im Wörterbuch zu finden bzw. nicht ohne das *vor sich* zu verstehen seien. Man findet einige auf der informellen Sprachebene angesiedelte Beispiele, wo das Sprachgefühl der Muttersprachler sich gerade umgekehrt entschieden hat und *hin* zum Verb stellt.

   a. Fälle, in denen ein *so* eingefügt ist.

   > Würde es die Trauung nicht geben, hätte es alles wohl weiter *vor sich **so** hin geplätschert*. [NWZ](https://www.nwzonline.de/oldenburg/kultur/zurueck-in-die-geborgenheit-des-glaubens-der-weg-zurueck_a_6,0,4107101743.html)

   b. Fälle, in denen das finite Verb eines Nebensatzes den infiniten Verben vorangestellt ist.

   > dass […] AV den Ruthenbeck eine Rückrunde lang ohne Perspektive *vor sich **hat** hin wurschteln* lassen. [Leserkommentar](https://geissblog.koeln/2019/10/totales-versagen-diese-pleite-hat-beierlorzer-beschaedigt/)

   c. Fälle, in denen *dahin* statt *hin* steht.

   > dem bis dahin eher seicht *vor sich **dahin** dümpelnden* Berliner Internationalen Tanzfest [Welt](https://www.welt.de/print-welt/article407211/Leichtfuessiger-Revolutionaer.html)

Noch zwei Bemerkungen zu 2c. Es steht für mich außer Frage, daß *vor sich dahin* als Einheit nicht existiert, während *dahin*+V üblich ist. Die Bedeutung entspricht dabei vielleicht nicht ganz der der infragestehenden Konstruktion.

> [dahinleben](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dahinleben) ohne äußere und innere Erregung, unberührt vom Ablauf der Zeit leben
>   [dahinreden](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dahinreden) etw. ohne Rücksicht auf Form und Inhalt äußern
>   [dahinkränkeln](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dahinkraenkeln) über längere Zeit hin immer ein wenig krank sein

Interessanterweise gibt es aber Belege, wo *dahin* und *vor sich hin* austauschbar erscheinen.

> den Text Shakespeares, den die Darsteller mal dahinmurmeln, mal herausschreien [SZ](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/muenchen/shakespeare-im-muenchner-residenztheater-liebeszombies-statt-sommernachtstraum-1.1383228-2)
>
> Die Erbsen, Möhren, Bohnen oder Schwarzwurzeln […] schmeckten gräßlich, weil sie zu lange dahingeköchelt hatten [Hellmann](https://books.google.de/books?id=oCM339BLMygC&pg=PA502&lpg=PA502&dq=dahingek%C3%B6chel)
>
> dahinschlafen  *vor sich hinschlafen* [GWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/GWB?lemma=dahinschlafen)

Comment: Zu 1: sehe ich umgekehrt, zu 2a: m.E. fehlerhaft für *so vor sich hin*, zu 2b: m.E. fehlerhaft für *hat vor sich hin ...*, zu *dahin ...*: sagst du schon selbst.